# How did Obi-Wan Kenobi know Luke's name in ANH?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope, obi-wan-kenobi

In *Star Wars: A New Hope* when Kenobi saves Luke from the Sand People and wakes him up. Without Luke giving his name, Kenobi calls him,

> "young Luke."

**Is there an explanation or is this just a movie mistake?**

Comment: It's pretty obvious that Luke and Obi-Wan already knew each other.

Comment: He calls him Ben. They're old friends.

Comment: I suspect this question is attracting downvotes due to a lack of research effort. That being said, actually *proving* that Ben would immediately recognise Luke took me some effort.

Comment: @Valorum what's to prove?  Are you saying that Lucas needed to establish a connection prior to revealing it later?  Let's say we had no idea about Obi's prior history with Luke and Anakin, doesn't the fact that Luke knows who "Old Ben" is, and later that Obi knew Luke's father and had fought with him in the Clone Wars pretty much wrap things up?

Answer (score 12):

Ben was present at Luke's birth and delivered him to his adopted parents at the end of *Revenge of the Sith*. He then installed himself in a nearby hovel to keep an eye on him and to defend him from potential attackers.

We see in the (canon) comics that he met with Luke on *multiple occasions* during his early years, initially visiting the family on occasion, then observing the boy from afar after his falling-out with Owen Lars, right up to age 17, just a couple of years before seeing him again in ANH.

**Luke age (approx) 4**
[image: Panel 1: Obi-Wan stands with his hood up in his Jedi robes overlooking a young Luke who is sat cross legged on the side of a small building: Obi-Wan thinks "Instead of Sith Lords and bounty hunters, my days were spent battling monotony and inactivity. I should have been busier than ever. I should have been training the boy." Panel 2: Close up on Luke still in the same position, Obi-Wan carries on: "But his uncle never allowed it. And I suppose there was a part of me that couldn't blame him."]
<sub><sup>[*Star Wars* #7](https://www.marvel.com/comics/issue/52658/star_wars_2015_7)</sup></sub>

**Luke age (approx) 7**
[image: Close up on Luke's head holding a box of parts excited wearing a cowboy hat with goggles on it covering long hair, he says "But these... these are... Skyhopper parts!" Panel 2: Zoomed out view of Luke now looking up "Ha ha! Thanks, Uncle Owen!" Panel 3: Luke races away with the parts, in the background Owen can be seen inspecting various droids, he calls to Luke "What was that? Thanks for what?" Panel 4: View over Owen's shoulder as he watches Luke race away, "Luke?" Panel 5: We see a hidden Obi-Wan with his hood up has been watching the whole situation and chuckles to himself about the confused Owen]
<sub><sup>[*Star Wars* #15](https://www.marvel.com/comics/issue/55764/star_wars_2015_15)</sup></sub>

**Luke age 13**
[image: Panel 1: Close up of a stern faced hooded Obi-Wan who says "Hurry up, I will get you home safely, Luke." Panel 2: Silhouetted view of Luke looking over his shoulder to look at the hooded figure of Obi-Wan behind him, he calls "Who. Who are you?" Panel 3: Close up of Obi-Wan removing his hood and saying "Ben Kenobi. You can call me Ben".]
<sub><sup>[*Star Wars Webcomic*: #1 - An Old Friend](https://www.webtoons.com/en/sf/starwars/ch-1-an-old-friend/viewer?title_no=544&episode_no=1)</sup></sub>

**Luke age 17**
[image: Panel 1: Close up of Luke with a mic to his mouth looking smug "Hah hah" Panel 2: An even closer look of his mouth smiling "I won." Panel 3: A hooded figure looks over the scene to a crashed T-16 smoking on the desert floor]
<sub><sup>[*Star Wars Webcomic*: #2 - Meeting the Droids](https://www.webtoons.com/en/sf/starwars/ch-2-meeting-the-droids/viewer?title_no=544&episode_no=2&webtoonType=WEBTOON)</sup></sub>

Comment: Skipping the prequels (if only!), when Luke tells his aunt and uncle about the msg in R2D2, he says "... I wonder if she means ol' Ben Kenobi." Luke knows of him.  Even as "served with your father in the Clone Wars", that version of Obi-wan would have kept track of Luke

Comment: Nice well researched answer! Makes me wonder why Obi Wan didn't do the old mind trick on Owen Lars if he wanted to train the boy so desperately?

Comment: @NeoDarwin - Owen doesn't strike me as being someone with an especially weak mind.

Answer (score 7):

They were next door neighbours.  Obi-Wan had known Luke all his life.  Later on in the prequels George Lucas had Obi-Wan be the one who had brought Luke to Tatooine and Obi-Wan was only living there because of Luke, having always planned to train Luke if he grew into a good prospect.

Comment: Can you offer any evidence to back up these statements?

Answer (score 1):

> **Luke:** The droid says he belongs to someone named 'Obi-Wan'.  Do you think he means Old Ben?

To me, it seems clear from his preceding conversation with his Uncle that they all knew who Old Ben was, and so it reasons that on a desert planet with a tiny population that Old Ben would know who Luke Skywalker was.